# mysql query unite 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table friends with 4 columns (id, sender, receiver, status) and I need a query that will unite (reunion, I dont know the word in english) the sender and receiver colums.
For example the table looks like this

```
| sender | receiver |
|    2   |   10     |
|    2   |    8     |
|    2   |    9     |
|    6   |    2     |
|    7   |    3     |
```

And the query should give only the unique ids from both sender and receiver. (2,3,6,7,8,10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.iResult
FROM
    (SELECT sender as iResult FROM tableName
        UNION
     SELECT receiver as iResult FROM tableName) a
ORDER BY iResult ASC
```

Returns

```
2
3
6
7
8
9
10
```

OR

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(b.iResult)
     (SELECT DISTINCT a.iResult
     FROM
             (SELECT sender as iResult FROM tableName
                 UNION
              SELECT receiver as iResult FROM tableName) a
         ORDER BY iResult ASC) b
```

returns

```
2,3,6,7,8,9,10
```

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a job for [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html):

```
select sender as id from <table_name>
union
select receiver as id from <table_name>
```

Note that `union` will remove duplicates (use `union all` if you want to keep duplicates).